# Double hline and no top left corner

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am trying to output a table looking like this:

[image]

That is, where the first line is separated from the rest with a double hline, and where the top left corner is empty.

The image above was obtained with the following code, but as you can see there is an alignment issue with it: the bottom line from the double hline is one "unit" too high compared to the height of the line above "A" and the height of the vertical separators.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|}
\hhline{~----}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hhline{~====}
\hhline{-~~~~}
A & B & C & D & E\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations of `\hline`, `\cline` and `\hhline` but every time there's always one thing not aligned properly.

I'm looking for a way to solve exactly this. Please do not answer this question with "double hlines look bad in tables, you shouldn't use them" or similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|}
\hhline{~----}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hhline{-====}
A & B & C & D & E\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had the same, but loading `array` did not solve the broken corner south west of "1". Do you have an idea?

Comment: This works, thanks. I don't see why `-` would output as the bottom line next to a `=` instead of the top one.That really doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @Fatalize tex boxes usually align on their baseline so the small box with top and bottom fragment specified by `=` and the box with a single fragment specified by `-` naturally align on the bottom. I could have made them align differently when defining `\hhline` but as you see here, this seems as useful as anything.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi ypu could use `\hhline{-:====}` for that one, although there are still notches at the corners of the standard hline, eg to left of A

Comment: @DavidCarlisle perfect. Add `\usepackage{array}` and `\hhline{~|----}` for the first and `\hhline{~:----}` for the second line and all notches are gone.